# Angular 4 + ASP.NET MVC 5 + Webpack build in VS 2015 and TFS

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, webpack, asp.net-mvc-5

Can anyone guild me on how to **setup asp.net mvc5 application with angular 4 (webpack)  in visual studio 2015 update 3**.

I want to know how to  integrate the webpack build with visual studio 2015 build process and in TFS continous integration.